# Aggregate Data between Polygons

Tags: polygon, arcgis-9.3, spatial-analyst, aggregate-points

I have data at the ZIP3 level and I need to join it to a state file. I also need the data within the zip3 file to be averaged, but for some reason when I use the join tools, i'm not getting the results that I need.

Is there a way to aggregate data from a zip3 level to a state level without swtiching over to raster data (which is what the spatial analyst tool requires).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS 10.3

Comment: Does the ZIP3 level information have a state ID associated with it? It's quite unlikely you will need to convert anything to a raster for this. Is your ZIP3 data in the form of polygons or points?

Answer (score 1):

The dissolve tool (ArcToolBox-->Data Management Tools-->Generalization-->Dissolve in 9.x) will join the shapes based on the State field and will allow aggregate functions such as sum, average, count, etc. on selected fields.  This will result in a new multi-polygon feature class.

Comment: The dissolve tool isn't helping here as I have ZIP 3 polygons with data in them that I want to aggregate up to state level. So lets say I have 5 Alaska zip3s and 7 for Alabama and nine for California, I need the output to be one line for Alaska, one like for Alabama, one line for California.
I'm going to try to find an ID field that I can use as the problem might be cominf from the use of state codes.

Comment: If you dissolve by State id, then can't you join the zip3 data (with its newly aggregated fields) to the state data?  I'm talking about a table join based on state id, not a spatial join.  I apologize if I'm not understanding the question correctly.

Comment: Following up to see if this was helpful.  Don't leave me hanging! :)